# v4l2 very simple example

Tags: c++, c, linux, v4l2, v4l

I'm looking for a **simple** example for camera access in Linux using V4L2.
Where I can find it? As simple, as possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 23):

Try the uvccapture code here -> http://staticwave.ca/source/uvccapture/
It is very small yet very **concrete** example which makes use of all the V4l2 concepts (open,set format, allocate memory, Request Buffer, Dqbuffer and Query-buffer - all intems of ioclts).

**uvcgrab**() function is the one to look for which makes use of Dqbuffer and Query-buffer.

```
ioctl (vd->fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &vd->buf);

ioctl (vd->fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &vd->buf)
```

While Studying it you can keep looking for the ioctl definition in this [link](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/) which will ease your understanding.

Answer (score 6):

In the API specification, there is an [example](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/capture-example.html), also downloadable as a [C file](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/v4l2spec/capture.c)

Comment: This example works fine for me, but it's a little bit complex. I found this one http://credentiality2.blogspot.com/2010/04/v4l2-example.html but it doesn't work for me :( I get read error 22, Invalid argument

Comment: The links are dead. I suppose that was [this one](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/media/uapi/v4l/capture.c.html), which works, but only outputs the image frames to stdout...

Answer (score 4):

I would advice also trying out v4l-utils.

http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-utils/

It has some easy to use API calls to v4l devices and there is a qt based example in the source to build a custom interface for video devices.