# linux/videodev.h : no such file or directory  - OpenCV on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-11.04

I tried to install OpenCV2.2 on Ubuntu 11.04. But OpenCV compilation fails stating an error related to linux/videodev.h file. 
File available in /user/includes/linux is named videodev2.h.

```
/home/user/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp:217:28: fatal error:    linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_v4l.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there a solution for this ?

thank you.

Comment: updated version is available at `https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk`. And `libv4l-dev` is need to be installed in addition to other libraries.

Comment: This error also occurs when compiling VXL. Alberto's answer, coupled with Niroshan's comment helped me solve it. You must make Niroshan's changes to these two files: $VXLSRC/contrib/oul/oufgl/frame_grabber_v4l.h and $VXLSRC/contrib/oul/oufgl/frame_grabber_vil.h

Comment: I just wanted to clarify, it is Niroshan's comment on Alberto's answer that fixes the issue for VXL.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
```

**Editing for RH based systems** :

On a Fedora 16 to install pygame 1.9.1 (in a virtualenv):

```
sudo yum install libv4l-devel
sudo ln -s /usr/include/libv4l1-videodev.h   /usr/include/linux/videodev.h
```

Comment: need to edit cap_v4l.cpp, replace #include <videodev.h> with #include <libv4l1-videodev.h> as suggested in the link provided by karlphillip

Comment: or better yet, just create a symlink to the file named videodev.h. No patching needed.

Comment: For those googling "linux/videodev.h": I fixed a different software (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10641571/778990) by linking videodev.h to videodev2.h.

Comment: How to symlink videodev.h? Well, refer to bukzor's answer below for that.

Answer (score 99):

The current answer is incomplete. Installing `libv4l-dev` creates a `/usr/include/linux/videodev2.h` but doesn't solve the stated problem of not being able to find `linux/videodev.h`. The library does ship header files for compatibility, but fails to put them where applications will look for them.

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
cd /usr/include/linux
sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
```

This provides a `linux/videodev.h`, and of the right version (1).

Comment: This worked for me for Pygame, which will not install from pip on Ubuntu 12.10 without this.

Comment: I'm installing Pygame as well and this also worked for me. If you're installing Pygame via pip (and not via apt), remember to also install pygame's dependencies: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203630/easy-install-pygame-not-working-due-to-linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-direct

Comment: also outlines in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694753/which-library-needed-to-satisfy-include-linux-videodev-h

Answer (score 3):

v4l support has been dropped in recent kernel versions (including the one shipped with Ubuntu 11.04).

**EDIT**: Your question is connected to a [recent message](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/79758) that was sent to the OpenCV users group, which has instructions to compile OpenCV 2.2 in Ubuntu 11.04. Your approach is *not ideal*.

Comment: I have few questions, that link tells to download libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev and libcv2.1 libcvaux2.1 libhighgui2.1 libraries. Don't they belong to two earlier versions of OpenCV? And later it tells to download OpenCV2.2 source code. Is this accurate? please explain me, I am not that familiar with OCV library. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The patch is here: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/attachment/ticket/862/OpenCV-2.2-nov4l1.patch

By adding `#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L` around

```
#include <linux/videodev.h>
```

in `OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp` and removing `|| defined (HAVE_CAMV4L2)` from line `174` allowed me to compile.

Answer (score 0):

for CMake remove/disable `with_libv4l` `with_v4l` variables if you do not need this lib.