# OpenCV, Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-11.04

I've been trying to install OpenCV 2.2 on Ubuntu 11.04. As far as I can gather from here: [linux/videodev.h : no such file or directory  - OpenCV on ubuntu 11.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842235/linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-directory-opencv-on-ubuntu-11-04), the installation fails because video4linux is no longer in the kernel. If I follow the guide linked to in the above thread (http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/79758), the make-command passes the initial error described in the above thread, but fails at a later point. I get the error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_createsamples
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.2.0: undefined reference to `cvCreateCameraCapture_V4L(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_createsamples] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This error also seems related to video4linux.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch,
Andreas Møgelmose

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux/videodev.h : no such file or directory  - OpenCV on ubuntu 11.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842235/linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-directory-opencv-on-ubuntu-11-04)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, this is a different error.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've managed to make it compile by disabling video4linux in the CMake config. This makes it possible to install the library, but has the rather unfortunate side effect of making it impossible to use USB cameras as input devices. So that's not really what I'm after.

Comment: The problem exist as a bug in the OpenCV Trac here: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/862 (with no solution)

Comment: The most recent SVN version compiles, but cannot load video files nor use attached cameras.

Comment: It is very strange... I was able to compile OpenCV 2.2 on Ubuntu 11.04 yesterday but after installed libgtk2-dev, rerun cmake and make I got the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: Latest svn version worked for me regarding video files. But I didn't test it for cameras. Hope you didn't miss libv4l-dev

Answer (score 2):

You may find this blog post useful:
http://salikscodingblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/compiling-opencv-2-on-ubuntu/