# OpenCV 2.2 Ubuntu11.04 Webcam not detected

Tags: opencv, webcam, ubuntu-11.04

I have checked out the OpenCV SVN repo, installed all necessary libraries, compiled it and installed it. Everything is fine, except that it won't find any cameras.

I currently have two webcams connected to my computer, the internal webcam and a PS3 eye.

`ls /dev/video*` gives

/dev/video0  /dev/video1

The video code:

```
VideoCapture capture(0);
if(!capture.isOpened())
{
   capture.open(1);
   if(!capture.isOpened())
      return 0;
}
```

There are no problems with opening video files instead of cameras.

I have tried to replace `#include <videodev.h>` with `#include <libv4l1-videodev.h>` in cap_v4l.cpp.

I have also tried the solutions [on the Ubuntu OpenCV bug 321358 thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opencv/+bug/321358).

Any good ideas what to do next?

The cameras works just fine with the Ubuntu repository version, but we are working on VSLAM, so we need newer stuff.

Comment: Write an _answer_ with the solution, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an explanation in [this post at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869397/opencv-ubuntu-11-04), if you look at the comments.

The short explanation is that in the 11.04 distribution, Canonical removed the support for a particular library. So, OpenCV 2.2 (release) cannot compile anymore on Ubuntu 11.04. So the people at OpenCV removed the support for webcams in the SVN. I suppose they'll try to fix it as soon as possible

> The most recent SVN version compiles, but cannot load video files nor use attached cameras

Comment: oh snap! i think i saw that comment, but did not understand that there where no webcam support at all.. lol, <sarcasm>this is a epic vision system library. it features everything except support for cameras. </sarcasm> ok, will have to work on an virtual machine in the meantime then.. Thanks :)

Comment: This problem is solved from revision 5099 and forward.
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/changeset/5099