# Which library needed to satisfy #include <linux/videodev.h>

Tags: c++, linux, raspbian

I'm trying to compile uvccapture on the Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Wheezy. What package do I need to install so gcc/make can satisfy this include?

```
#include <linux/videodev.h>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev

maybe you will need also:

> cd /usr/include/linux
>   sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h