# linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

Hi I run into a problem when setting up my web camera for use in Chrome, which needed FlashCam.

When following the installation guide at: http://www.swift-tools.net/Flashcam/

At the step when doing the "make" build I get:

```
adderollen@andreas-RC530:~/Downloads/flashcam-1.4.5$ make
(cd vloopback; make);
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/adderollen/Downloads/flashcam-1.4.5/vloopback'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/adderollen/Downloads/flashcam-     1.4.5/vloopback modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic'
CC [M]  /home/adderollen/Downloads/flashcam-1.4.5/vloopback/vloopback.o
/home/adderollen/Downloads/flashcam-1.4.5/vloopback/vloopback.c:166:28: fatal error:    

linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
#include <linux/videodev.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [/home/adderollen/Downloads/flashcam-1.4.5/vloopback/vloopback.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/adderollen/Downloads/flashcam-1.4.5/vloopback] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic' 
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/adderollen/Downloads/flashcam-1.4.5/vloopback'
make: *** [vloopback/vloopback.ko] Error 2
```

So I googled some and found this: [linux/videodev.h : no such file or directory  - OpenCV on ubuntu 11.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842235/linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-directory-opencv-on-ubuntu-11-04)

I followed the answer by bukzor, but I still got the same problem. Any one got a solution?

I run Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you still have such a file on disk? If so, then may be the package which contains such a file was renamed, or may be file was renamed/removed.

Comment: It  seems like I don't... I only got the "videodev2.h", "videodev.o" and "videodev.ko". How do I create it?

Answer (score 0):

find / -name 'videodev.h'

locate videodev.h

using the above commands to check whether you have the file.

Comment: It seems like I don't... I only got the "videodev2.h", "videodev.o" and "videodev.ko". How do I create it?

Comment: After install libv4l-dev, you should include 'libv4l1-videodev.h' instead.

Comment: I did this: sudo ln -s /usr/include/libv4l1-videodev.h   /usr/include/linux/videodev.h